# Python hmac (sha1) calculation

Tags: python, hmac, hmacsha1

I am trying to calculate the HMAC-SHA1 value in Python, but results don't match with the standard tool I am using as reference (openSSL):

**Python**

```
k = "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
m = "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
key = k.decode("hex")
msg = m.decode("hex")
print xlong(hmac.new(key, msg=msg, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest())
```

Result: `801271609151602865551107406598369208989784139177`

**OpenSSL**

```
echo -n ‘ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff’ | xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha1 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Result: `8c5a42f91479bfbaed8dd538db8c4a76b44ee5a9`

Comment: Might the python output be a decimal representation? It contains no A-F at all.

Comment: @Norman yes indeed:  `>>> hex(801271609151602865551107406598369208989784139177)
'0x8c5a42f91479bfbaed8dd538db8c4a76b44ee5a9'
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) on the HMAC:

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> print hexlify(hmac.new(key, msg=msg, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest())
8c5a42f91479bfbaed8dd538db8c4a76b44ee5a9
```

Or you may just use `str.encode('hex')`:

```
>>> print hmac.new(key, msg=msg, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest().encode('hex')
8c5a42f91479bfbaed8dd538db8c4a76b44ee5a9
```