# How can I SHA1-HMAC a string in Python

Tags: python, hash, sha1, hmac

I've been trying to figure out how to use HMAC to hash a string in Python for a TOTP generator I've already made in PHP. In PHP, I use the command `echo -n "0x00000000035362f9" | xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha1 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:0080700040024c8581c2` which returns the desired value `7289e7b135d54b86a462a53da93ef6ad28b902f8`. However, when I use the `hmac` library in Python 3.10

```py
from hashlib import sha1
from hmac import new

key = "00000000035362f9"
msg = "0080700040024c8581c2"

byte_key = bytes(key, "UTF-8")
message = msg.encode()

print(new(byte_key, message, sha1).hexdigest())
print(new(message, byte_key, sha1).hexdigest())
```

The printed values are `b05fe172b6a8a20767c18e1bfba159f0ea54c2bd` and `0fe109b32b17aeff840255558e6b5c8ff3d8a115`, neither match what I want.

I've tried making the key and message hex values first, I've made them raw bytes using `b'0080700040024c8581c2'`, encoding them using UTF-8 and ASCII, and none of the solutions have worked.

I've looked at other post relating to this, and none of them worked. 
[Python hmac (sha1) calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034637/python-hmac-sha1-calculation) 
[Python HMAC OpenSSL equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62966599/python-hmac-openssl-equivalent) 
[hmac returning different hexdigest values to openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029229/hmac-returning-different-hexdigest-values-to-openssl) 
[Why Python and Node.js's HMAC result is different in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303874/why-python-and-node-jss-hmac-result-is-different-in-this-code) 
[Implementing SHA1-HMAC with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518872/implementing-sha1-hmac-with-python)

Comment: Your Python code is treating both `key` and `msg` as arbitrary strings, not as hexadecimal numbers.  Applying `binascii.unhexlify()` or `bytes.fromhex()` to both of them would be one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jasonharper's answer from the comments was correct.

```py
from hashlib import sha1
from hmac import new
from binascii import unhexlify

msg = unhexlify("00000000035362f9")
key = unhexlify("0080700040024c8581c2")

print(new(key, msg, sha1).hexdigest())
```